# How to execute mysql commands in sh

Tags: bash, mysql

I try to write a script, which create database and tables in it.

For example, my bash file create attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u root -p
use dbname;
create......
.......
exit;
```

Is executed joining into mysql console and that all. Script not create any table in database and not executed exit from mysql console.

How to correct create the script for that task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of different ways to do this. The easiest may be

```
mysql -u root -p <<EOF
use dbname;
create ....
....
exit;
EOF
```

This feeds everything between the command line and the `EOF` into mysql as input.

Comment: Easiest, and exactly that what I need. Thanks!